# No sound via hdmi on youtube and online video players, VLC works fine

Tags: sound, video, hdmi, youtube

I have a weird problem. When I want to watch a youtube video on my television  (HDMI) I switch the sound via soundsettings to go through hdmi. But no sound is played on the television. Whenever I play a video on VLC, or play music via rhythmbox, this problem is not present. In other words, the audio is played fine via hdmi on my TV.

This problem is present on my Lenovo Ideapad u330p AND my Asus Zen UX305F.

My girlfriend's laptop still runs 14.04 and there the problem is not present. Is this a bug?

Edit: the audio in VLC works fine: in VLC one has the option to choose the audio device. Even if in sound settings the speakers are the sound device, I can choose to play video via hdmi in VLC. And this does seem to work.

Comment: what are you using to watch youtube ? A work-around is to download the video with `youtube-dl` and play it with `vlc`.

Comment: I just use Chrome. Switching to Firefox won't work. Your workaround would certainly work, if it is needed in say an 'emergency' case, but obviously sound from youtube should work in a browser, no?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Is it only in Youtube? There are many other video streaming website you can use for troubleshooting. If it's only Youtube then there's something wrong with your account settings.

Comment: No, not only in youtube, upon further investigation I have no audio via hdmi at all, except for VLC, where you have a built-in option to switch the audio device from built-in speakers to HDMI.

Comment: Interestingly, the 'test sound' option (Sound Settings) DOES work via HDMI. But not always immediately. When I click on either speaker (right or left) it might pop a little. And the second time I hear 'front left' or 'front right'...

Comment: Even more interestingly, in some cases also VLC does not work. I guess this will have to do with which codec is used for the encoding for the video.